# Surface Energy Calculation

Tags: finite-element-method

I have the following problem which is shown as:

[image]

The field variable $d$ is assigned a unit scalar value within radius $r = 5$ at the center of a square plate.

The multi-field equations are solved, $n$ denotes the outward normal to $\partial \Omega$.

[image]

The surface energy $\psi_i$ distribution is calculated at the integration points.

$\psi = \sum_{i}^{}\int_{\Omega}^{} 0.5*d_{i}^{2} + 0.5*\nabla d_{i} \cdot \nabla d_{i} d\Omega$

My question is about how can I determine the complete surface energy $\psi$.

Comment: Do you fill the space with dots "d" and calculate the surface energy for each ?

Comment: @GiovanniBaez, yes, it is so.

Comment: Is this question really so that easy that the vote is '-1' ?

Comment: The -1 is probably because theres is no code. When you ask a question, you should provide at least what you tried. Some code so that users can play with it. You question is maybe  overlooked because you gave no starting point. You are asking people to solve the problem without giving anything in return or at least showing you tried.

Comment: Supid question alert: Shouldn't the energy be equal to 0?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher , Surface energy should not be zero(Laplace is not zero) where is the routine for the energy value?

Comment: Don't you realize that the integrand of your energy expression is 0 due to the PDE you gave us?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, I think that I use the correct  equations in forum. Is it okay that I can send you this journal paper which includes this example?

Comment: Indeed, it would be a good idea to post a link to the paper in the original question.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, last equation in the post has been modified.

Comment: In general people like when you a) provide some code and b) show what you've already tried *or* explain *exactly* where you are stuck. Outside of the true altruists like @HenrikSchumacher it is too much work for most people to first have to parse what you want, create code from that, validate that they're doing the right thing, and then finally satisfy any finally conditions that posters that don't provide initial code generally have.

Comment: @b3m2a1, okay, may I ask you a very simple question, can you please let me know, How do I get the value of user defined surface energy in the 2D-area? see last equation for more details. I hope that I can solve this problem using your proposed method in Mathematica.

Comment: ABCDEMMM, not until you show what you have tried and where you got stuck

Comment: @b3m2a1, It sounds very good! thanking you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Discretizing the domain:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
R = ToElementMesh[
   RegionDifference[
    Rectangle[{-50, -50}, {50, 50}],
    Disk[{0, 0}, 5]
    ],
   MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> 50/50}
   ];
```

Solving the PDE:

```
u = NDSolveValue[{
    d[x, y] - Laplacian[d[x, y], {x, y}] == 
     NeumannValue[0, x^2 + y^2 > (5 + 1)^2],
    DirichletCondition[d[x, y] == 1, x^2 + y^2 < (5 + 1)^2]
    },
   d,
   {x, y} ∈ R
   ];
```

Plotting the solution:

```
Plot3D[u[x, y], {x, y} ∈ R, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

The energy can be obtained like this:

```
0.5 Integrate[
  u[x, y]^2 + Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}].Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}], 
  {x, y} ∈ MeshRegion[R]
]
```

> 17.2138

This integral takes quite long to evaluate, so I provide also a faster method using the low level functions behind the FEM capacities of `NDSolve`:

```
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables", "Space"} -> {{d}, {x, y}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space"} -> {R}];
cdata = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd,
   "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{-IdentityMatrix[2]}},
   "MassCoefficients" -> {{1}}
   ];
bcdata = InitializeBoundaryConditions[vd, sd,
   {{
     DirichletCondition[d[x, y] == 1, x^2 + y^2 < (5 + 1)^2],
     NeumannValue[0, x^2 + y^2 > (5 + 1)^2]
     }}
   ];
mdata = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];
dpde = DiscretizePDE[cdata, mdata, sd];
dbc = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[bcdata, mdata, sd];
{load, stiffness, damping, mass} = dpde["All"];
A = mass + stiffness;
DeployBoundaryConditions[{load, A}, dbc];

uvec = LinearSolve[A, load, Method -> "Pardiso"];
u = ElementMeshInterpolation[{R}, uvec];
energy = 0.5 Flatten[uvec].(mass + stiffness).Flatten[uvec]
```

> 17.2141

Comment: thanks a lot! The energy functional calculation is really not that easy for new MMA users, but why this question got many 'down vote'?

Comment: I hope that this question can be opened that many people can learn how to calculate the energy in solids using MMA. I think It should be a very helpful topic. Keep Real, it seems not that easy using simple commands in MMA. Also how to use parallel solver Pardiso in MMA.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM You're welcome. Towards the downvotes: rhermans, halirutan, b2m2a1,and me discussed about this post a bit in chat some time ago. The main reason might be that there was no code at all. Usually, we like OPs to invest some effort in the problem description and in prepairing as much code as is necessary to get start "right away". Often, this helps us also to estimate how deep the OP has already dived into the matter. It is not easy starting from zero -- also when trying to provide a good answer.

Comment: @Hennrik Schumacher, Good to know, I think the reason could be that, some 'experts' thought this question was too easy. Okay, I will remember this 'rule' here.

Comment: @Henrick Schumacher, If I use the second solution, I get the following error "Set::shape: Lists {load,stiffness,damping,mass} and DiscretizePDE[InitializePDECoefficients[{None,{x,y},{d},{},{},{},{},{}},{None,R,{},{},{},{},{},{}},DiffusionCoefficients->{{{{-1,0},{0,-1}}}},MassCoefficients->{{1}}],InitializePDEMethodData[{None,{x,y},{d},{},{},{},{},{}},{None,R,{},{},{},{},{},{}}],{None,R,{},{},{},{},{},{}}][All] are not the same shape."

Comment: You have to execute the first part also. In particular, you need to load ``Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];``.

Comment: the second method is really fast, thanks a lot!